# How to change color of specific items returen from map list

Tags: reactjs, map-function

I want to change border or outline color when I click for one item not all list items
but when I click on any items all list changed

I'm trying to change one item color not all...so when I change state it changed for all not for item I clicked

```
  const [color,setColor]=useState('');



type Values = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  color:string;
};


const myList2:Array<Values> =[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Suitcase',
    image: suitcase,
    color:'blue',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Briefcase',
    image: briefcase,
    color:'aqua',
  },{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Handbage',
    image: handbage,
    color:'red',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Multy',
    image: multy,
    color:'green',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Backpack',
    image: backpack,
    color:'gray',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: 'Family',
    image: family,
    color:'orange',
  },
]


  const listImage=myList2.map((item,i) => {
    return <span key={i}>
        <img  key={item.id}  style={{borderColor:color}}     onClick={()=>setColor(item.color)} src={item.image} alt={item.title}   />
    </span>
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are setting only color name in the state variable but not specify that for which index this color will apply

So simply store only index to the state variable on which user click by adding **onClick={()=>setActive(i)}** in the image tag

and finally check the condition in style by adding **style={{borderColor: active == i ? item.color : 'transparent', borderWidth: 3}}** in the image tag

```
const [active,setActive]=useState(-1);

type Values = {
id: number;
title: string;
image: string;
color:string;
};


const myList2:Array<Values> =[
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Suitcase',
    image: suitcase,
    color:'blue',
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Briefcase',
    image: briefcase,
    color:'aqua',
},{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Handbage',
    image: handbage,
    color:'red',
},
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'Multy',
    image: multy,
    color:'green',
},
{
    id: 5,
    title: 'Backpack',
    image: backpack,
    color:'gray',
},
{
    id: 6,
    title: 'Family',
    image: family,
    color:'orange',
},
]


const listImage=myList2.map((item,i) => {
    return <span key={i}>
        <img  key={item.id}  style={{borderColor: active == i ? item.color : 'transparent', borderWidth: 3}}     onClick={()=>setActive(i)} src={item.image} alt={item.title}   />
    </span>
})
```

Comment: give the color based on active item

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id` for that. So instead of only the color `name`, keep two pieces of information as an **object inside the state variable** => `id, color`.

**Like this:**

```
const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState({});


  const listImage=myList2.map((item,i) => {
    return <span key={i}>
        <img key={item.id} 
             style={item.id === selectedList.id ? { borderColor: selectedList.color } : {}}     
             onClick={() => setSelectedList({id: item.id, color: item.color})} 
            src={item.image} alt={item.title}   />
     </span>
  })
```